# $.post compatiblity with .on("mouseenter")

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I already have a couple `$.post`'s working in my file. The current one I'm trying to send is:

```
$("#rbody").on("mouseenter", ".date, .quarter", function(e) {
    $.post("classinfo.php",
        {
            id: $("td").attr("value");
        },
        function(data) {
            $("#classinfo").html(data);
     });
});
```

The `td` data is inputted via another AJAX call:

```
$(".rselector").change(function() {
    $.post("reservation.php",
        {
            reserve: $("#result").val();
        },
        function(data) {
            $("#rinfo").html(data);
     });
});
```

Because the `td` element is inputted after the DOM loads, I have the .on function. The other functions that is running under `.on("mouseenter", ...)` works fine until I add the `$.post`. Does `$.post` not work with `.on`? I've looked everywhere, and I can't find any documentation that addresses that. I've even copied the code for a previous AJAX call, and just changed the appropriate fields, but that entire script will break when I try to add the `$.post`.

EDIT:

This is the code before it breaks:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var moveLeft = 20;
var moveDown = 10;

    $("#rbody").on("mouseenter", ".date, .quarter", function(e) {
        $("#classinfo").show()
        .css("top", e.pageY + moveDown)
        .css("left", e.pageX + moveLeft)
        .appendTo("body");
    }).on("mouseleave", ".date, .quarter", function() {
        $("#classinfo").hide();
    });

    $("#rbody").on("mousemove", ".date, .quarter", function(e) {
        $("#classinfo").css("top", e.pageY + moveDown).css("left", e.pageX + moveLeft);
    });
});
</script>
```

This addition breaks the entire script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var moveLeft = 20;
var moveDown = 10;

    $("#rbody").on("mouseenter", ".date, .quarter", function(e) {
        $.post("classinfo.php",
            {
                id: $("td").attr("value");
            },
            function(data) {
                $("#classinfo").html(data);
        });
        $("#classinfo").show()
        .css("top", e.pageY + moveDown)
        .css("left", e.pageX + moveLeft)
        .appendTo("body");
    }).on("mouseleave", ".date, .quarter", function() {
        $("#classinfo").hide();
    });

    $("#rbody").on("mousemove", ".date, .quarter", function(e) {
        $("#classinfo").css("top", e.pageY + moveDown).css("left", e.pageX + moveLeft);
    });
});
</script>
```

Let me know if there's anything else you'd like to see.

Comment: see: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: `$.post()` on `mouseenter` without a throttling timer is not a good idea IMHO. That said, are you positive the functions that run after the call to `$.post()` do not modify content that will be reset when the AJAX response arrives?

Comment: I don't recognize this as a valid use of `$.post()`. Please see docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @PHPglue, [`$.post(url, data, success)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). What's the problem?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The other functions only show the previously hidden `#classinfo` div. Without the `$.post` only an empty div appears, but I want to populate the content of the div with the data pulled from `classinfo.php`

Comment: @rlemon I reviewed the link you shared, but I don't see anything that's helping my issue
@PHPglue What do you mean by your comment? There's nothing wrong with the syntax, as far as I can tell, and I even copied and edited the code for a previously working `$.post()` with the same result.

Comment: @Joseph, assuming there is no problem with your markup (please post the relevant parts of it in your question to help us deal with that hypothesis), then maybe `$.post()` on `mouseenter` actually breaks your browser after a while. In passing, are you sure you're delegating `mouseenter` and not `mouseover`? I was under the impression `mouseenter` events could not be delegated in the first place.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I added the full code. Let me know if there's anything else you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it. You have a spurious semicolon in an object literal that is causing a syntax error:

```
$.post("classinfo.php", {
    id: $("td").attr("value");  // <-- There.
}, // ...
```

That code should be:

```
$.post("classinfo.php", {
    id: $("td").attr("value")
}, // ...
```

In the future, remember to consult your browser's error console so you can catch this kind of problem right away.

Comment: When I get enough of a reputation, I'm going to upvote you so hard.

Comment: @Joseph, that's very kind of you, however the [serial voting threshold](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) will revert your efforts if you try too hard ;)